# Getting Started with Azure Web App Bug Hunting

Tags: web

I have had my website (webapp) setup now on Azure now for 1.5 years. Most of the time it has been relatively smooth going.

Lately the average response time and number of server errors being thrown is increasing. I recently migrated the site over to https and am wondering if that could be the source of the errors and slow down ?

I am not very confident of my ability to interpret the raw log files (even if I could locate them). Where is the best place to start looking through the azure system  to discover whats going on ? A starting point if you will ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I will start here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/

Answer (score 0):

@Mark

**Application Insights** indeed is the best way.

Alternatively, you can enable FREB to capture logs about a request when the response time crosses a certain threshold or if it encounters an **HTTP ERROR**.